# Divide Tuple into multiple tuples

Tags: apache-pig

I have tuples which don't contain the same amount of data:
(a, b, c, d)
(e, f)
(g, h, i)

What i would like to do is to create new tuple for each data:
(a)
(b)
(c)
(d)
(e)
(f)
(g)
(h)
(i)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a relation A, then the below statement will give you the required output.

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(ToBag(*));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you produce your required results (Have tested it):

```
Data:
a,b,c,d
e,f
g,h,i
```

Let's say you have this data in a relation, A.

```
A  = LOAD 'data file' using PigStorage(',');
```

Next statement converts each row to a bag, this is required for the next step to produce the required result. After this operation each record/tuple will have one element, a bag.

```
 B = foreach A generate TOBAG(*);
```

Flatten takes each element from the bag and puts them in separate row.

```
C = foreach B generate flatten($0);

dump C;
(a)
(b)
(c)
(d)
(e)
(f)
(g)
(h)
(i)
```